# dplyr::case_when giving warnings about RHS of cases which should not be evaluated

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when, forcats

I have a `tibble` where one column is an ordered factor containing the names of the components of a decomposed time series; I want to change these because they are not easily comprehensible ("level" is not to my mind as clear as "trend", and "weekly" and "annual" are better names than "season1" and "season2").

Sometimes I get "season1" and "season2", but sometimes just "season". I am using `dplyr::mutate`, `dplyr::case_when` and `forcats::fct_recode`. In the case where the first option of the `case_when` statement matches, I would expect that it would pay no attention to any of the others.

However, in the case when I am testing for a given level and then changing the name of that same level, it is throwing a warning

> "Warning: Unknown levels in `f`"

about the level changed in the next case. I know it's only a warning and the output is right, but it is annoying me and I want to know what I did wrong.

I am using `dplyr 0.8.0.1` and `forcats 0.4.0` on `R 3.4.4`.

```r
# This throws a warning about unknown levels: a

library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

d <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = as.ordered(c("ab", "d", "e")))

d %>%
  mutate(b = case_when(
    "ab" %in% levels(b) ~ fct_recode(b, foo = "ab"),
    "a" %in% levels(b) ~ fct_recode(b, bar = "a"),
    TRUE ~ b
  ))
```

```
# This doesn't generate a warning

library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

d <- tibble(a = 1:3, b = as.ordered(c("ab", "d", "e")))

d %>%
  mutate(b = case_when(
    "ab" %in% levels(b) ~ fct_recode(b, foo = "ab"),
    "a" %in% levels(b) ~ fct_recode(b, bar = "d"),
    TRUE ~ b
  ))
```

Expected result: b has levels "foo", "d" and "e" with no complaints.

Actual result: levels correct, but "## Warning: Unknown levels in `f`: a"

Comment: You only have levels `c("ab", "d", "e")` hence the warning.

Comment: But it shouldn't be evaluating that line!

Comment: Why not as you have it here: `"a" %in% levels(b) ~ fct_recode(b, bar = "a"),`?!

Comment: a) It has already matched the first option in the case_when; b) "a" %in% levels(b) is a condition, which did not match. The error is from fct_recode

Comment: I think the first and second options are independent of each other. The first option doesn't seem to introduce "a" as a new level hence it really has no effect on the second "match". Did you run both pieces of code independent of each other?

Comment: This is a min reprex. The second line kind of made sense in practice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192672/discussion-between-s-j-cowtan-and-nelsongon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That's because `case_when` executes all of the right-hand sides (RHS)
> and then keeps everything that satisfies left-hand side (LHS).

`case_when` will evaluate `fct_recode(b, bar = "a")` even when `"a" %in% levels(b)` is `FALSE`. That's why it gives a warning.

mishabalyasin, from comunity.rstudio.com, found the answer. See [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/case-when-with-heterogeneous-date-formats/28465).